# How to use link_to that has an <i> tag inside it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanna make the **a tag** here be a **link_to** helper:

```
<td class="text-center">
<a href="#">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
</a>
</td>
```

I tried to make it like this:

...loop code for the @events and  then:

```
<%= 
link_to "", controller: "events", action: "edit", id: event.id do
%>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
<% end %>
```

But the url that is coming is wrong, not an edit link. How do I make it right?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Remove the first empty string option. `link_to controller: "events", action: "edit", id: event.id do`

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the 'link_to' helper should not be provided with a 'do' block as it will override the block you pass to it. If you provide one (even an empty string) as you have then it uses that instead, so remove the first argument as so:

```
<%= 
  link_to controller: "events", action: "edit", id: event.id do
%>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
<% end %>
```